# How Can we get the Google Pagerank through PHP without third party API

Tags: php, pagerank

Please provide the suitable codes for online Google Pagerank display, We can not place the third party API for getting this. We can use the API from Google only. If anybody have the codes for Pagerank that would be Good for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/*****************************************/
define('GOOGLE_MAGIC', 0xE6359A60);

  function _zeroFill($a, $b){
    $z = hexdec(80000000);
    if ($z & $a){
      $a = ($a>>1);
      $a &= (~$z);
      $a |= 0x40000000;
      $a = ($a>>($b-1));
    }else
      $a = ($a>>$b);
    return $a;
  }

  function _mix($a,$b,$c){
    $a -= $b; $a -= $c; $a ^= (_zeroFill($c,13));
    $b -= $c; $b -= $a; $b ^= ($a<<8);
    $c -= $a; $c -= $b; $c ^= (_zeroFill($b,13));
    $a -= $b; $a -= $c; $a ^= (_zeroFill($c,12));
    $b -= $c; $b -= $a; $b ^= ($a<<16);
    $c -= $a; $c -= $b; $c ^= (_zeroFill($b,5));
    $a -= $b; $a -= $c; $a ^= (_zeroFill($c,3));
    $b -= $c; $b -= $a; $b ^= ($a<<10);
    $c -= $a; $c -= $b; $c ^= (_zeroFill($b,15));
    return array($a,$b,$c);
  }

  function _GoogleCH($url, $length=null, $init=GOOGLE_MAGIC){
    if(is_null($length))
      $length = sizeof($url);
    $a = $b = 0x9E3779B9;
    $c = $init;
    $k = 0;
    $len = $length;
    while($len >= 12){
      $a += ($url[$k + 0] + ($url[$k + 1] << 8) + ($url[$k + 2] << 16) + ($url[$k + 3] << 24));
      $b += ($url[$k + 4] + ($url[$k + 5] << 8) + ($url[$k + 6] << 16) + ($url[$k + 7] << 24));
      $c += ($url[$k + 8] + ($url[$k + 9] << 8) + ($url[$k + 10] << 16) + ($url[$k + 11] << 24));
      $_mix = _mix($a,$b,$c);
      $a = $_mix[0]; $b = $_mix[1]; $c = $_mix[2];
      $k += 12;
      $len -= 12;
    }
    $c += $length;
    switch($len){
      case 11: $c += ($url[$k + 10] << 24);
      case 10: $c += ($url[$k + 9] << 16);
      case 9 : $c += ($url[$k + 8] << 8);
      case 8 : $b += ($url[$k + 7] << 24);
      case 7 : $b += ($url[$k + 6] << 16);
      case 6 : $b += ($url[$k + 5] << 8);
      case 5 : $b += ($url[$k + 4]);
      case 4 : $a += ($url[$k + 3] << 24);
      case 3 : $a += ($url[$k + 2] << 16);
      case 2 : $a += ($url[$k + 1] << 8);
      case 1 : $a += ($url[$k + 0]);
    }
    $_mix = _mix($a,$b,$c);
    return $_mix[2];
  }

  function _strord($string){
    for($i = 0;$i < strlen($string);$i++)
      $result[$i] = ord($string{$i});
    return $result;
}

  function getPageRank($url){
    $pagerank = -1;
    $ch = "6"._GoogleCH(_strord("info:" . $url));
    $fp = fsockopen("www.google.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if($fp){
      $out = "GET /search?client=navclient-auto&ch=" . $ch . "&features=Rank&q=info:" . $url . " HTTP/1.1
";
      $out .= "Host: www.google.com
";
      $out .= "Connection: Close

";
      fwrite($fp, $out);
      while (!feof($fp)){
        $data = fgets($fp, 128);
        $pos = strpos($data, "Rank_");
        if($pos === false){
        }else
          $pagerank = substr($data, $pos + 9);
      }
      fclose($fp);
    }
    return $pagerank;
}
/*******************************************/
```

add above code to your script and call getPageRank($url) function which will return you exact page rank of given url.

Comment: I just tried this and it doesnt work anymore as of mar 7, 2012

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://www.pagerankcode.com/ or http://www.bewebmaster.com/141.php

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefered this Link [PHPClasses](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2682-PHP-Retrieve-the-Google-page-rank-of-a-given-URL.html). It is an API but Open-Source and i don't know why it must be selfwriten?